# ASP.NET ListBox Trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Here is all my code:

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div class="main">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Site.Master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox ListBox1 = new ListBox();
            ListBox1.FindControl("ListBox1");
            ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why is my ListBox not populating?

When running the code I get a page with a small box that is completely empty.

I tried the following already and I will tell you the result -

- Remove

`ListBox ListBox1 = new ListBox();`
`ListBox1.FindControl("ListBox1");`

Result: The name 'ListBox1' does not exist in the current context

- Add a reference to ListBox1 manually into the designer.

Result: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

To fix that error adding the line `ListBox ListBox1 = new ListBox();` works, but still does not display.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello", "H"));
        }
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14atsyf5%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) too

**EDIT**: Same code works for me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would be willing to bet that your _Default.aspx.cs does not contain a definition for ListBox1.  If this entry is not present, manually add it

Comment: @JohnAtrik, I have added the 2nd arg (this isn't actually required).  I have seen this before, and either clean solution -> rebuild, or restart VS.

Comment: @Jeff Fritz I did do that as I said and got the error mentioned above.

Comment: @christiandev The addition of the "H" did nothing, still says that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Ack, I listed the wrong filename...  You should have a definition in Default.aspx.designer.cs   That is where all controls in the markup are mapped to c-sharp.

Comment: @JeffFritz protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox ListBox1; Did that and did nothing but generate error: Object reference not set to an instance ot an object.

Comment: @christiandev Restarting VS got rid of the error, but still an empty ListBox.

Comment: @JohnAtrik, and your code is exactly like mine? put a break on the page_load event and make sure it's being hit.

Comment: @christiandev It is being hit, and the "Hello" is going inside the list, but it does not display when ran.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question of why `ListBox1` isn't getting populated:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListBox ListBox1 = new ListBox();  //You are creating a new local ListBox named ListBox1.
     ListBox1.FindControl("ListBox1");  //You are trying to find the Control named ListBox1 that is held within the Control ListBox1 (and not doing anything with the result of the search)
     ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello"));  //You are adding a new ListItem to the local ListBox1.
}
```

As christiandev said, you should just be able to do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello"));
}
```

I have no idea why you can't seem to access the ListBox1 on the aspx page.